# how to pass a class method as argument to another method of the class in perl 6

Tags: raku, function-object

I have a script like the below. Intent is to have different filter methods to filter a list.

Here is the code.

```
  2 
  3 class list_filter {
  4   has @.my_list = (1..20);
  5 
  6   method filter($l) { return True; }
  7 
  8   # filter method
  9   method filter_lt_10($l) {
 10     if ($l > 10) { return False; }
 11     return True;
 12   }
 13 
 14   # filter method
 15   method filter_gt_10($l) {
 16     if ($l < 10) { return False; }
 17     return True;
 18   }
 19 
 20   # expecting a list of (1..10) to be the output here
 21   method get_filtered_list_lt_10() {
 22     return self.get_filtered_list(&{self.filter_lt_10});
 23   }
 24 
 25   # private
 26   method get_filtered_list(&filter_method) {
 27     my @newlist = ();
 28     for @.my_list -> $l {
 29       if (&filter_method($l)) { push(@newlist, $l); }
 30     }
 31     return @newlist;
 32   }
 33 }
 34 
 35 my $listobj = list_filter.new();
 36 
 37 my @outlist = $listobj.get_filtered_list_lt_10();
 38 say @outlist;
```

Expecting [1..10] to be the output here. But getting following error.

```
Too few positionals passed; expected 2 arguments but got 1

  in method filter_lt_10 at ./b.pl6 line 9
  in method get_filtered_list_lt_10 at ./b.pl6 line 22
  in block <unit> at ./b.pl6 line 37
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I noticed that your "less than 10" and "greater than 10" methods are identical. Also, I can't exactly tell which lines your errors are on.

Comment: thanks for pointing. Have corrected and added line numbers.

Comment: Have asked this as another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095399/perl-6-passing-methods-as-arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing a method as a parameter in Perl 6 either requires you to use MOP (Meta-Object Protocol) methods, or pass the method by name (which would then do the lookup for you at runtime).

But why use `method`s if you're not really doing something with the object in those methods?  They might as well be `sub`s then, which you **can** pass as a parameter.

Perhaps this is best by example:

```
class list_filter {
    has @.my_list = 1..20;  # don't need parentheses

    sub filter($ --> True) { } # don't need code, signature is enough

    # filter sub
    sub filter_lt_10($l) { not $l > 10 }

    # filter sub
    sub filter_gt_10($l) { not $l < 10 }

    # private
    method !get_filtered_list(&filter_sub) {
        @.my_list.grep(&filter_sub);
    }

    # expecting a list of (1..10) to be the output here
    method get_filtered_list_lt_10() {
        self!get_filtered_list(&filter_lt_10);
    }
}

my $listobj = list_filter.new();
my @outlist = $listobj.get_filtered_list_lt_10();
say @outlist; # [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
```

The first `sub filter`, which only returns a constant value (in this case `True`), can be represented much more easily in the signature with an empty body.

The `filter_lt_10` and `filter_gt_10` subs only need the condition negated, hence the use of the `not`.

The `get_filtered_list` method is supposed to be private, so make it a private method by prefixing `!`.

In the `get_filtered_list_lt_10` you now need to call `get_filtered_list` with a `!` instead of a `.`.  And you pass the `filter_lt_10` sub as a parameter by prefixing the `&` (otherwise it would be considered a call to the sub without any parameters, which would fail).

Change the `get_filtered_list`to use the built-in `grep` method: this takes a `Callable` block that takes a single parameter and which should return something `True` to include the value of the list it works upon.  Since a `sub` taking a single parameter **is** a `Callable`, we can just specify the sub there directly.

Hope this made sense.  I tried to stay as close as possible to the intended semantics.

Some general programming remarks: it feels to me that the naming of the subs is confusing: it feels to me that they should be called `filter_le_10` and `filter_ge_10`, because that's really what they do it appears to me.  Also, if you really don't want any ad-hoc filtering, but only filtering from a specific set of predefined filters, you would probably be better of by creating a dispatch table using constants or `enum`s, and use that to indicate which filter you want, rather than encoding this information in the name of yet another method to make and maintain.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and code improvement suggestions.

Comment: Tried in my actual code. The problem with making filter_lt_10 into a sub is that it does not allow itself to be overridden by a derived class. I want to have derived classes override my filter mechanism yet still have the same base class get_filtered_list get me back different lists.

Answer (score 3):

The `&{self.method}` syntax was new to me, so thanks for that. Unfortunately it doesn't work if parameters are needed. You can use `sub` as other posters mentioned, but if you need to use methods, you can get a method by calling `self.^lookup`, which is the use of the meta-object protocol that Elizabeth mentioned. ('^' means you're not calling a method that's part of that class, but rather part of the "shadow" class which contains the main class's guts / implementation details.)

To get a method, use run `obj.^lookup(method name)`, and call it by passing in the object itself (often "self") as the first parameter, then the other parameters. To bind the object to the function so it doesn't need to be explicitly added each time, use the [assuming](https://docs.raku.org/routine/assuming) function.

```
class MyClass {
  method log(Str $message) { say now ~ " $message"; }
  method get-logger() { return self.^lookup('log').assuming(self); }
}
my &log = MyClass.get-logger();
log('hello'); # output: Instant:1515047449.201730 hello
```

Comment: Perl 6 actually has syntax for method lookup: `my $a = "say"; 42."$a"()` will call the `.say` method on `42`.  Note that you **must** have parentheses, even if you don't pass any parameters.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen That doesn't allow the functions to be passed. Are you assuming the OP should pass around strings (method names) rather than the methods themselves? I'm a strongly typed guy, so I wouldn't do that if there's any way to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks. Combination of both your answers/comments is what worked for me. Posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095399/perl-6-passing-methods-as-arguments/48095824#48095824

Comment: Interesting. I suppose another way would be to add indirection (that is `{$foo.meth1: $^a}`)

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** You told P6 what arguments to expect when calling your `filter` method. Then you failed to pass the agreed argument(s) when you called it. So P6 complained on your behalf. To resolve the issue, either pass the argument(s) you told P6 to expect or stop telling P6 to expect them. :)

---

The message says expected `2`, got `1`, rather than expected `1` got `0`.

This is because `self` is implicitly passed and added to the "expected" and "got" totals in this appended bit of message detail, bumping both up by one. (This detail is perhaps Less Than Awesome, i.e. something we should perhaps consider fixing.)

---

When I [run your code on tio](https://tio.run/##pVTLbsIwELzzFSsVVUFqI8Khl7SIU6Xee48M2SSunIdsB4oQ356u7YSaABISPiXex8zsTtKgFG9dN5kAnY1gSoHgSicZFxolHFwAoGAKVmG5T0wUPiCIwnAxn8UU7jOeYMeFgDVCvUUpecqrHHTBFfAKUpR8i6lDQNWXlKiLOgWHFUzFDA4gUbeygm/ZYgxHv71iJUIjeaWHwq8T5IYJYfAyWZdAz@eAUK9/cKNHsLZVLxRTKywgBn0Spe1hVbe6F6xQZGGO44Lngw24y6OdhzuK/ZcPt2dyCH7LNJ5zugLgXhOXMOZX4W5YiIed1dJb1usSpsKrA@AZjPqa4ZvpN60qgqHrC9XN3BL@@bvTb2nI9AV6Mi/8lAidRHPgY5PdtMPEp0wqlhDNPZd8MqEwvuRl3XMvp/xBTu8Pc6JNTg042TSiVV4MLKQxm/3a5FNmeNXAMVkLfxuyu/ke6CslbQXFr2AtRlj5TazFXVj2l2DBuu4P) I get:

```
Too few positionals passed; expected 2 arguments but got 1
  in method filter at .code.tio line 27
  in method print_filtered_list at .code.tio line 12
  in block <unit> at .code.tio line 42
```

The method *declaration* `method filter($l) {...}` at line 27 tells P6 to expect *two* arguments for each `.filter` method *call*:

- The invocant. (This will be bound to `self`.) Let's call that **argument A**.
- A positional argument. (This will be bound to the `$l` parameter). Let's call that **argument B**.

But in `&{self.filter}` in line 12, while you provide the `.filter` method *call* with an **argument A**, i.e. an invocant argument, you don't provide an **argument B**, i.e. a positional argument (*after* `filter`, e.g. `&{self.filter(42)}`).

Hence `Too few positionals passed; expected 2 arguments but got 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Found it. this is what worked for me.

```
  3 class list_filter {
  4   has @.my_list = (1..20);
  5 
  6   # will be overriding this in derived classes
  7   method filter1($l) { return True; }
  8   method filter2($l) { return True; }
  9 
 10   # same print method I will be calling from all derived class objects
 11   method print_filtered_list($type) {
 12     my @outlist = self.get_filtered_list($type);
 13     say @outlist;
 14   }
 15 
 16   # private
 17   method get_filtered_list($type) {
 18     my @newlist = ();
 19     for @.my_list -> $l {
 20       my $f = "filter$type";
 21       if (self."$f"($l)) { push(@newlist, $l); }
 22     }
 23     return @newlist;
 24   }
 25 }
 26 
 27 class list_filter_lt_10 is list_filter {
 28   method filter1($l) {
 29     if ($l > 10) { return False; }
 30     return True;
 31   }
 32   method filter2($l) {
 33     if ($l > 10) { return False; }
 34     if ($l < 5) { return False; }
 35     return True;
 36   }
 37 }
 38 
 39 class list_filter_gt_10 is list_filter {
 40   method filter1($l) {
 41     if ($l < 10) { return False; }
 42     return True;
 43   }
 44   method filter2($l) {
 45     if ($l < 10) { return False; }
 46     if ($l > 15) { return False; }
 47     return True;
 48   }
 49 }
 50 
 51 my $listobj1 = list_filter_lt_10.new();
 52 $listobj1.print_filtered_list(1);
 53 $listobj1.print_filtered_list(2);
 54 
 55 my $listobj2 = list_filter_gt_10.new();
 56 $listobj2.print_filtered_list(1);
 57 $listobj2.print_filtered_list(2);
 58
```

Output:

```
./b.pl6
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
[5 6 7 8 9 10]
[10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
[10 11 12 13 14 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

piojo's answer looks like it would work (though I haven't tried it).

Another approach to turning a method into a variable is to use indirection:

```
class Foo {
    method bar($a) {
        $a * 2
    }
}

sub twice(&f, $x) {
    f f $x
}

my $foo = Foo.new();
say twice {$foo.bar: $^a}, 1
```